# Reusing Yesod widgets in AJAX results

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm writing a [very simple Yesod message list](https://github.com/eightyeight/floating-castle-2421) that uses AJAX to add new list items without reloading the page (both in the case of other users modifying the database, or the client themselves adding an item). This means I have to encode the HTML structure of the message items in both the Halmet template (when the page loads initially) and the Julius template (for when the dynamic addition happens). They look something like this:

In `homepage.hamlet`:

```
$if not $ null messages
    <ul id=#{listId}>
        $forall Entity mid message <- messages
            <li id=#{toPathPiece mid}>
                <p>#{showMarkdown $ messageText message}
                <abbr .timeago title=#{showUTCTime $ messagePosted message}>
```

And in `homepage.julius`:

```js
function(message) {
    $('##{rawJS listId}').prepend(
        $('<li>')
        .attr('id', message.id)
        .append('<p>' + message.text + '</p>')
        .append($('<abbr class=timeago />')
                .attr('title', message.posted).timeago())
        .slideDown('slow')
    );
}
```

I'd love to be able to unify these two representations somehow. Am I out of luck, or could I somehow abuse widgets into both generating an HTML response, and filling in code in a JavaScript file?

`Note:` Of course, I understand that the templates would have to work very differently, since the AJAX call is getting its values from a JS object, not from the server. It's a long shot, but I thought I'd see if anyone's thought about this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's something of a AJAX best-practice to pick *one* place to do your template rendering, either on the server or client. Yesod is (currently) oriented toward doing the rendering on the server.

This can still work with AJAX replacement of contents, though. Instead of getting a JSON response from the POST, you should get a text/html response that contains the result of rendering the template on the server with the values that would have been returned via JSON and then replacing the innerHTML of the DOM node that's being updated.

If you want to support both JSON and HTML responses (to support 3rd party applications via API or something) you would have to make the format of the response be a function of the request; either appending ".json" or ".html" to the URL or including a HTTP header that lists the specific document type required by the client.

It would be nice if Yesod provided a 'jwhamlet' template or something that would render the HTML via javascript in order to support client rendering, but I'm not aware of one. That's not to say there isn't one I'm not aware of, though, so keep an eye open for other answers.

If you wanted to make such a thing, you might try tweaking the hamlet quasi-quote code so that instead of expanding the quasi-quotes to an html-generating function, it expanded them to a JSON-generating function *and* a pre-rendered chunk of text that's a template in mustache-style such that the JSON returned by the function would provide the correct context for the template to be rendered the way you want.

Comment: Thanks! I did consider sending HTML, and that approach probably makes more sense anyway. Yesod does already allow you to ask for HTML or JSON responses (or any other) based on the request type.